# Sandcastle Help File Builder and VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sandcastle

how to add a sandcastle help file builder project (.shfbproj) to a visual studio 2008 solution?

Comment: You might want to clarify your question.  Do you want to simply keep the shfbproj as part of your solution (in the solution tree) or are you wanting to integrate the building of documentation as part of your solution's build process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to create Sandcastle docs inside Visual Studio: [DocProject](http://www.codeplex.com/DocProject)

To quote the project web site:

> DocProject drives the Sandcastle help
>   generation tools using the power of
>   Visual Studio 2005/2008 and MSBuild.
>   Choose from various project templates
>   that build compiled help version 1.x
>   or 2.x for all project references.
>   DocProject facilitates the
>   administration and development of
>   project documentation with Sandcastle,
>   allowing you to use the integrated
>   tools of Visual Studio to customize
>   Sandcastle's output.

Marc

Comment: Does anyone know of some sort of mirror or place I can download DocProject? I have to work with Visual Studio 2008 for work and my manager wants to use Sandcastle. Unfortunately it seems that codeplex has been shutdown and I cannot find DocProject anywhere.

Comment: @Daisy: how about here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DaveSexton.DocProject - first hit when googling "DocProject" .....

Comment: Thanks. I had not even thought to check the Microsoft store.